# Different ClickOnce deployment URL for each build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm working with C#, VS and ClickOnce. Is there way to specify which URL the ClickOnce should publish to based on the build name? Say I have Build X and Build Y - whenever I select to publish Build X, I want the ClickOnce URL field to be pre-populated with a URL **just** for Build X and when I select Build Y, it's pre-populated **just** for Build Y. Right now it just has the URL for whatever was published more recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to change the URL in visual studio programmatically. You could do the build using msbuild and sign the deployment using mage, and automate it this way.

Comment: We have a solution for several of our applications at work that uses msbuild and mage - we spent quite a lot of time working out whether it could be done and it seems that msbuild/mage is the answer.

Comment: Agreed. And if you write a script, it removes the possibility of making manual errors, too. Not that any of us have ever typed in the installation URL wrong or anything.  ;-)

Comment: Rob, any chance you can leak it over to the chat?  Before reading this post, thats is how I thought it was going to have to be done, but if you have the command line params already, that would be a great headstart.  If not, no biggie.  We are trying to evaluate if we want to go with ClickOnce or just some MSIs with version checking  in the application.